# c++ rearranging an integer

Tags: c++, integer, palindrome

I'm currently a C++ student and I'm on the basics part of C++, so please excuse me if this seems simple for you guys but I find it the hardest problem I ever had:
It is given a number n with exactly 8 digits. Find the biggest palindrome number obtained by the rearrangement of all digits of n.
Example: 21523531 => 53211235

I know vectors and how to check if a number is palindrome, I also know how to remove each digit from a number until it gives me a palindrome number, but I have no ideea how I can rearrange ALL digits.

Comment: This is more of a general "how would you do it?" question as opposed to a C++ question.  In other words, a strategy first, then the program second.

Comment: You have not supplied any visible readable source code showing what you have tried and what kind of errors you are getting against what you are expecting as a result. It is hard for people to answer your question without the needed information.

Comment: It's not that I have errors, the problem is the strategy. I have no clue from where to start.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the sample data will always produce a palindrome?

Comment: Note that every answer thus fair fails with input 135797531. People are overlooking the problems caused by INT_MAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think followng code will work:

```
int func(int x) // returns 0 if there is no valid palindrome
{
    int arr[10]{};
    while (x)
    {
        arr[x%10]++;
        x /= 10;
    }
    for (int it : arr)
        if (it % 2)
            return 0;
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i]/2; j++)
            ret = ret * 10 + i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i]/2; j++)
            ret = ret * 10 + i;
    return ret;
}
```

And here is more student-readable version:

```
int func(int x) // returns 0 if there is no valid palindrome
{
    int arr[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; // it is digits counter
    while (x) // this is executed for each digit in the number
    {
        arr[x%10]++; // here x%10 is equal to current digit
        x /= 10; // remove rightmost digit
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2) // Every digit must be repeated 0,2,4,6 or 8 times. If it's not, then there is no valid palindrome
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    int ret = 0; // this is our future result
    // Now we just take largest digit that appears in source number and add it to the result. If it appears twice, we add it once. If it appears 4 times, we add it twice and so on.
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i]/2; j++)
        {
            ret = ret * 10 + i;
        }
    }
    // Now we're doing same thing in the reverse direction.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i]/2; j++)
        {
            ret = ret * 10 + i;
        }
    }
    return ret; // we're done now
}
```

I hope you'll find this answer usefull and will use it without blind copy.

Comment: The code is working and now I'm trying to understand some things from it. Thank you very much for the comments you put in, it makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple logic. At first count number of different digits from 0-9. If different digits are not more than 4 then count the instance of each each digit. If each digits are even number then find the the 4 largest digit(all digits can equal).
sort them decreasing order first and increasing order second.
This will works.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to test it and reply with the result.

Answer (score 0):

In an even k digit palindrome number, every digit d occurs

```
n(d) = 2 * m(d), m(d) in |N u {0}
```

times.

Just reverse-sort the digits into an array `source` and 
(in pseudo code)

```
for i=0 to i = (k/2)-1
do
   target[i] = target[k-1-i] = source[i*2];  
done
```

Now try and code that in C++.